# Change animation of my div to slide out from right to left, instead of fade in

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a website and at the moment I have a button that when clicked will fade in a div, and fade out on another click (Toggle class).

I've changed my mind and want to have the div that fade in to now slide out from the right hand side, and then when toggled again will slide back to the right and disappear.

I have the below code already, which works with fading in, but I can't seem to figure it out to have it slide out from the right instead?

```
$('.menubutton').click(function() {
    $('.newMenu').fadeToggle('280');
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, format your code to complete your question. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you post some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
 $('#menu').toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
#menu {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: width 300ms ease;
   background: #EEE;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu.open {
  width: 256px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.menu-button {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #DDD;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu-button">Open/Close menu</a>

<div id="menu">
  This is the menu div
</div>
```